# Getting error CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object when trying to use .apply()

Tags: javascript

I've created a simple little route parsing function so that I can keep my code clean and easily maintainable, this is the little function that gets ran when the app starts up and parses the `config.json` file and binds the appropriate methods and request paths:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
module.exports = function(app, root) {
  fs.readdirSync(root).forEach((file) => {
    let dir = path.resolve(root, file);
    let stats = fs.lstatSync(dir);
    if (stats.isDirectory()) {
      let conf = require(dir + '/config.json');
      conf.name = file;
      conf.directory = dir;
      if (conf.routes) route(app, conf);
    }
  })
}

function route(app, conf) {
  let mod = require(conf.directory);

  for (let key in conf.routes) {
    let prop = conf.routes[key];
    let method = key.split(' ')[0];
    let path = key.split(' ')[1];

    let fn = mod[prop];
    if (!fn) throw new Error(conf.name + ': exports.' + prop + ' is not defined');
    if (Array.isArray(fn)) {
      app[method.toLowerCase()].apply(this, path, fn);
    } else {
      app[method.toLowerCase()](path, fn);
    }
  }
}
```

The problem I have is some times I need to pass in multiple arguments to an express router, e.g. in the case of using passport something like this:

```
exports.authSteam = [
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect("/");
  }
];
```

So I figure I can just pass them as an array, and then parse them into the router appropriately, my config for example looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Routes for the authentication",
  "description": "Handles the authentication",
  "routes": {
    "GET /auth/facebook": "authFacebook",
    "GET /auth/facebook/return": "authFacebookReturn"
  }
}
```

The only problem is I'm getting this error:

```
     app[method.toLowerCase()].apply(this, path, fn);
                                ^

TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object
```

if I `console.log(fn)` I see `[ [Function: authenticate], [Function] ]`

I'm not exactly sure what I am doing wrong, any information would be great thanks.

Comment: Had the same error. The error message does not help at all.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You need to send the params as an array, like this:

`app[method.toLowerCase()].apply(this, [path, fn]);`

If you want to send an arguments list you need to use call:

`app[method.toLowerCase()].call(this, path, fn);`

Source: [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: **a**pply **a**rrays and **c**all **c**omma-separated lists

Answer (score 5):

Fixed it by changing:

`eval.apply(this, 'p1', 'p2')`

to:

`eval.apply(this, ['p1', 'p2'])`

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, so i verified that node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js was received

```js
Socket.prototype.onevent = function(packet){
  var args = packet.data || [];
  debug('emitting event %j', args);

  if (null != packet.id) {
    debug('attaching ack callback to event');
    args.push(this.ack(packet.id));
  }

  emit.apply(this, args);
};
```

so i changed to:

```js
Socket.prototype.onevent = function(packet){
  var args = packet.data || [];
  debug('emitting event %j', args);
    
  if (null != packet.id) {
  debug('attaching ack callback to event');
  args.push(this.ack(packet.id));
  }
    
  emit.apply(this, [args]);
 };
```

it's solve to me

Comment: I see no modification between the two code snippets ?

Comment: Joffrey i fix the answer